# Community User Navigation Menu

Tags: community, customer-community, community-builder

I have created a Community User and cloned the community user profile and added the required objects to it. Out of which there is an Object "Invoice" which is part of Managed package to whom I have given Read and View All Permission.

I wanted this object tab in the Napili Template for which I followed the below steps :

1. Clicked Community Builder
2. Clicked Page Editor
3. Selected Navigation Menu
4. Here wile adding the tab when I enter salesforce Object I do not see the Invoice object in the list. Also I checked it is not displaying any objects related to the managed package.

I have added the Invoice object in the tabs and also the profile in the member of the community.

I have also tried giving licence access of the package to the community user.

So please let me know why is that object not displaying in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The Invoice object probably isn't on the list because it's part of the managed package which hasn't been released for use in a Community. Only standard objects that are available for the community type and custom objects you've created will be visible along with managed package objects that have been released for use in Communities. Check the managed package to see if it's available for use in a Community. You may need a separate license from the vendor to use it in your Community.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your quick reply.
Can you please let me know the steps how to check if a managed package is available for Use in a Community.

Comment: @RushabhShah Look at the information in Setup under Installed Apps for information about the App. You'll likely find it there. Otherwise, you'd need to check with the vendor and/or their listing on the App Exchange. If it isn't specifically listed as being available for use within communities, it most likely isn't.